# correct parameters to download file using Amazon s3 API GET requests

Tags: r, amazon-s3, get, amazon-web-services, httr

I would like to be able to download a `.csv` file from my Amazon S3 bucket using R.

I have started using the API that is documented here http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html

I am using the package `httr` to create the `GET` request, I just need to work out what the correct parameters are to be able to download the relevant file.

I have set the `response-content-type` to `text/csv` as I know its a `.csv` file I hope to  download...but the response I get is as follows:

```
Response [https://s3-zone.amazonaws.com/bucket.name/file.name.csv?response-content-type=text%2Fcsv]
  Status: 200
  Content-type: text/csv
Date and Time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
2007/01/01 22:51:00,5683.00,5683.00,5673.00,5673.00,64
2007/01/01 22:52:00,5675.00,5676.00,5674.00,5674.00,17
2007/01/01 22:53:00,5674.00,5674.00,5673.00,5674.00,42
2007/01/01 22:54:00,5675.00,5676.00,5674.00,5676.00,36
2007/01/01 22:55:00,5675.00,5676.00,5675.00,5676.00,18
2007/01/01 22:56:00,5676.00,5677.00,5674.00,5677.00,64
2007/01/01 22:57:00,5678.00,5678.00,5677.00,5677.00,45
2007/01/01 22:58:00,5679.00,5680.00,5678.00,5680.00,30
 .../01/01 22:59:00,5679.00,5679.00,5677.00,5678.00,19
```

And no file is downloaded and the data seems to be in the response...I can extract the string of characters that is created in the response, which represents the data, and I guess with some effort it can be converted into a `data.frame` as originally desired, but is there a better way of downloading the data...straight from the `GET` command, and then using `read.csv` to read the data? I think that it is a parameter issues...just not sure what parameters need to be set for the file to be downloaded.

If people suggest the conversion of the string...This is the structure of the string I have...what commands would I need to do to convert it into a `data.frame`?

```
chr "Date and Time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume\r\n2007/01/01 22:51:00,5683.00,5683.00,5673.00,5673.00,64\r\n2007/01/01 22:52:00,5675."| __truncated__
```

Thanks

HLM

Comment: Do you have code and a publicly accessible URL that could be used for testing?

Comment: I found one of similar construction. See if the combination of reading directly from the `GET` value and using `colClasses=` improves performance.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your second question:

```
> chr <- "Date and Time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume\r\n2007/01/01 22:51:00,5683.00,5683.00,5673.00,5673.00,64\r\n"
> read.csv(text=chr)
        Date.and.Time Open High  Low Close Volume
1 2007/01/01 22:51:00 5683 5683 5673  5673     64
```

If you want extra speed for the read.csv, try this:

```
chr <- "Date and Time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume\r\n2007/01/01 22:51:00,5683.00,5683.00,5673.00,5673.00,64\r\n"
 read.csv(text=chr, colClasses=c("POSIXct", rep("numeric", 5) ) )
```

Assuming the URL is set up properly (and we have nothing to test this on yet) I'm wondering if you may want to look at the value for `GET( ...)$content`

Perhaps:

```
infile <- read.csv(text=GET(...)$content, colClasses=c("POSIXct", rep("numeric", 5) ) )
```

## Edit:

That was not correct because the data comes across as "raw" format. One needs to convert from raw before it will become encoded as text. I did a quick search of Nabble (it must be good for something after all) to find a csv file that was residing on the Web. This is what finally worked:

```
read.csv(text=rawToChar( 
                 GET(
                  "http://nseindia.com/content/equities/scripvol/datafiles/16-11-2012-TO-16-11-2012ACCEQN.csv"
                   )[["content"]] ) )
  Symbol Series        Date Prev.Close Open.Price High.Price Low.Price Last.Price Close.Price
1    ACC     EQ 16-Nov-2012     1404.4    1410.95    1410.95   1369.45    1374.95      1378.1
  Average.Price Total.Traded.Quantity Turnover.in.Lacs Deliverable.Qty X..Dly.Qt.to.Traded.Qty
1       1393.62                132921          1852.41           56899                   42.81
```

Comment: So much better than my attempts to reinvent the wheel.  Likely faster too.

Comment: that simple solution works out quite well actually...but now the biggest holdup appears to be at the conversion of the response to the character string...using `content`...the code I am currently using is `x <- GET(end.point, add_headers(Date=time.string,Authorization=authorization.string), query=params)`

  `y <- read.csv(text=content(x))`

any ideas on how to speed that up?

Comment: My guess is that the server response is quite a bit slower than the `read.csv` step. Have you profiled it with `system.time`? (Also: Using colClasses is known to speed up all `read.*` functions.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
library(taRifx) # for stack.list
test <- "Date and Time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume\r\n2007/01/01 22:51:00,5683.00,5683.00,5673.00,5673.00,64\r\n2007/01/01 22:51:00,5683.00,5683.00,5673.00,5673.00,64\r\n"
stack( sapply( strsplit( test, "\\n" )[[1]], strsplit, split="," ) )

    [,1]                  [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      
ret "Date and Time"       "Open"    "High"    "Low"     "Close"   "Volume\r"
new "2007/01/01 22:51:00" "5683.00" "5683.00" "5673.00" "5673.00" "64\r"    
new "2007/01/01 22:51:00" "5683.00" "5683.00" "5673.00" "5673.00" "64\r"
```

Now convert to a data.frame:

```
testdat <- stack( sapply( strsplit( test, "\\n" )[[1]], strsplit, split="," ) )
rownames(testdat) <- seq(nrow(testdat)) # Because duplicate rownames aren't allowed in data.frames
colnames(testdat) <- testdat[1,]
testdat <- testdat[-1,]
as.data.frame(testdat)
        Date and Time    Open    High     Low   Close Volume\r
2 2007/01/01 22:51:00 5683.00 5683.00 5673.00 5673.00     64\r
3 2007/01/01 22:51:00 5683.00 5683.00 5673.00 5673.00     64\r
```

Comment: You can split on `"\\r\\n"` instead if it's going to return the Windows line endings as in the example.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for that, is there a way to quickly remove `\r` bit too?...but eitherway the file is quite large >75MB and so data transforms from character to data.frame like that seem to take a long time....so its not the ideal solution at the moment, given that the s3 data has already been uploaded as a csv file...am still hoping for the parameter values to adjust the API request to just download the data.

Comment: Replace `strsplit( test, "\\n" )` with `strsplit( test, "\\r\\n" )`, or just `gsub( "\\r", "", test) before you run any of the other code.  I'm not sure what you mean by "just download the data," as it seems to me that what it gave you is the data, in comma-separated form.

Comment: perhaps I should have said "just download the file" rather than getting the data in comma separated form...from the get request...